# Promoting products in posts: does it play a role if it is free or commercial?

Tags: discussion

Related to this question: [What should we do when we have a serial answerer to promote a product?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5395/what-should-we-do-when-we-have-a-serial-answerer-to-promote-a-product)

Does it play a role, when a user promotes a product in their post (an answer), if this product is OpenSource / available free of cost or if it is a commercial product, requiring a payment to use it? So should we take that aspect into consideration or is the kind of access (gratis vs. with costs) completey irrelevant?

Answer (score 3):

*We already had a little discussion in comments of an answer to that other question but its gone, i'll try to repeat it:*

I think no, there should be no difference in treating OpenSource or commercial promotions, as long as the promoted product is an answer to the question and the answerer indicates their association to their product, if there is an association.

Our community, and every single member of it, is free to choose for theirselves whether they prefer OpenSource or commercial products and we, as community, should not prefer one over another and should not set a direction our members should go. We are not a software support site for any specific product, so there should be no difference in treating the different products and categories. *(Aside from the fact that we may have more members knowing this software than that software and therefore have more answers for this software)*

Of course one could argue, that the promotion of commercial products may be profit oriented and therefore of less quality, while promoting OpenSource may not. **But:** I think **as long as the product is an answer to question**, this argument does not really matter.

If a product is **clearly** not an answer to the question, it should be flagged as spam, no matter whether it is commercial or OpenSource.

Comment: But what if the question is planted in the first place?